# routerlink = "functionName()" invoked immediately upon page load

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

My component's html is this:

```
<div id="summary">
  <div *ngFor="let question of thisSurvey">
    <div>
      <span class="badge">#{{question.questionNumber}}</span>
      <span>{{question.questionText}}</span>
    </div>
    <p>Your answer: {{question.questionAnswer}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>

<button class="btn btn-danger yes-no-btn" routerLink="/survey">Go Back</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="submitSurvey()" routerLinkActive="active">Finish</button> <!-- Issue here -->
```

When the page loads, submitSurvey is invoked immediately, and is then constantly invoked. This is submitSurvey:

```
  // Send the answers back to the api for processing
  submitSurvey() {
    // Make sure everything is answered
    const allOKClientSide: boolean = this.surveyService.checkEntireForm(this.thisSurvey);

    if (allOKClientSide) {
       if (this.surveyService.checkFormOnline(this.thisSurvey).subscribe()) {
        return '/placeOne';
       }
    }

    return '/placeTwo';
  }
```

The method begins to hit the service immediately and continues until I kill the server. How do I keep the function from being invoked until the button is clicked? I'm new to Angular and am probably just making a rookie mistake, if so you may point that out as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: note: If `SurveyService.checkFormOnline()` returns an `Observable` then what resolves in that `if` statement is a `Subscription` which is "truthy" so will always be true.

Comment: routerLink should not be used for this purpose. Consider using (click) event on your button instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[routerLink]` is an Input, note the `[]`. So Angular will resolve that immediately and every change detection cycle, to satisfy the template. You want to use `(click)` which is an Output, note the `()` and will only call when the button is clicked. Then instead of returning the url on the `submitSurvey()` function call router.navigate() (inject the router first.)

html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitSurvey()" routerLinkActive="active">Finish</button>
```

ts

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

public submitSurvey(): void {
  // Make sure everything is answered
  const allOKClientSide: boolean = this.surveyService.checkEntireForm(this.thisSurvey);

  if (allOKClientSide) {
    if (this.surveyService.checkFormOnline(this.thisSurvey).subscribe()) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/placeOne');
      return;
    }
  }

  this.router.navigateByUrl('/placeTwo');
}
```

Comment: That works just fine, appreciate it! Thanks for the explanation as well, it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You want your method to be called when the button is clicked. You can do this by using `(clicK)`:

Instead of

```
[routerLink]="submitSurvey()"
```

do

```
(click)="submitSurvey()"
```

Then you use the router in your class to do the navigation:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

submitSurvey() {
    // ...
    this.router.navigate(['/placeOne']);
}
```

Comment: `[routerLink]="nextRoute"` will just set link but not navigate to it. I think you should use `Router.navigate` instead

Comment: You're right, the `(click)` will probably not reliably run before the `[routerLink]`, so I've updated the answer with  your suggestion. Thanks